# Change normal text to time VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Below is the code.

1. The values in A:A is all set to general in the actual sheet (OTA)
   Need to change that to time format. IS there a way to get that done

Any help is appreciated I'm just starting out with VBA. Thanks in advance

```
Dim ws, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim TimeAdd As String

    'Delete the created sheet
    TimeAdd = "00:15"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Data").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Setting up the sheet and copy the data to the sheet "Data"

    Set ws = Sheets("OTA")
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Data"
    ws.Range("E:E").Copy Worksheets("Data").Range("A:A")
    ws.Range("O:O").Copy Worksheets("Data").Range("B:B")
    Worksheets("Data").Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "0000"   

    'Copying the formula thru the column "C"

    Set ws2 = Sheets("Data")
    LR = ws2.Range("B" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws2.Range("C2:C" & LR).Formula = "=B2+" & TimeAdd

End Sub'''
```

Comment: `TimeAdd = """00:15"""`

Comment: Try using the macro recorder to determine the code you need to change the number format. Also, generally questions should be restricted to one issue, not multiple.

Comment: Got your point thank you very much..